# Getting "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches" prompt message while running a Java Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm making a program to find the integer that is middle in value in java.  It doesn't seem to work and I can't launch it. It is giving me this error `" the selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches"`.  Here is an image in the link, scene I don't have enough reps.

[image: Image of error on Imgur]

I have tried to recreate another project, but it also didn't work. It gave me the same error. Below is the code:

```
public class J1 {

public static void main(int[] ar) {
    //define variables
    int i;
    int large;
    int small;
    //Program
    for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
        int x = ar[i];
        int y = ar[i - 1];
            if (x > y){
                x = large;
            }
            else if(x < y){
                x = small;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }

    //after the for loop


}

}
```

Comment: Because of main method parameter. It must be a String array.

Comment: change `public static void main(int[] ar) {` to `public static void main(String[] args) {` should work fine